# Choice between ETL or Java Based solution

Tags: java, sql, database, etl

I'm conceptualising a new solution where in my first step, i need to centralize Data from different sources( Databases, Excel Files, CSV files...) into a temporary Database before starting my controles and batches, this will allow me to have a good starting point which will not be affected by the changes in my sources’ data, the question is what's the best solution for me, an ETL like Talend or Pentahoo , or a java based solution with a spring batch? thank you verry much for your answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talend (or Pentaho) gives you all the necessary components to do what you want with very limited hand coding.
On the other side, if you want to do everything by yourself...

Comment: That's why i tought too, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out AWS Glue.  It is in preview stage now but you can sign up for access.  Once there you can manage everything in their cloud for free for a long time.  https://aws.amazon.com/glue/